# Migrating from Dataflow 2.5.0 SDK to Beam 2.13 release

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I got an error message saying Dataflow 2.5 (Java) is the last supported release and I should use Beam.  Is there a migration guide? I can find Dataflow 1.x to 2.x but not Dataflow to Beam.

For example, DataflowPipelineOptions doesn't seem to be installed if you use the maven archetype suggested in the Beam documentation.

Specifically: 
`import org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.options.DataflowPipelineOptions`
is not found when I use the pom.xml generated using:

```
mvn archetype:generate \
      -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.beam \
      -DarchetypeArtifactId=beam-sdks-java-maven-archetypes-starter \
      -DarchetypeVersion=2.13.0 \
      -DgroupId=com.myexample \
      -DartifactId=newpackage \
      -Dversion="1.1" \
      -DinteractiveMode=false
```

even after adding:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java</artifactId>
  <version>2.13.0</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

to the generated pom.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a few additional Google Cloud dependencies in your pom.xml in order to run your Beam pipeline on Dataflow. Things worked for me after I added:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java</artifactId>
  <version>${beam.version}</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform</artifactId>
  <version>${beam.version}</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-extensions-google-cloud-platform-core</artifactId>
  <version>${beam.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-extensions-protobuf</artifactId>
  <version>${beam.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>${beam.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

In addition, you may need to add a few more parameters to your startup script. I had to add:

```
gcpTempLocation=gs://$BUCKET/tmp
```

Comment: Hi @Lak, good work finding the solution! Can you accept your own answer? It will make it more visible and help someone with the same issue as you find the solution. Thanks!

Comment: only after 2 days (StackOverflow rules), but I will do so.

Answer (score 0):

This [blog post](https://shinesolutions.com/2017/05/22/beam-me-up-google/) may be helpful. A user here described their migration.

I believe the package renaming (com.google.cloud.dataflow to org.apache.beam) and new class/method signatures is already done if you're on [Dataflow 2.x SDKs](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/migrate-java-1-to-2).

So I think in this case the migration should be straightforward. Please try removing the Dataflow SDK and introducing [org.apache.beam on the lastest version](https://beam.apache.org/get-started/downloads/). It may work without modification. You could also try using org.apache.beam on 2.5 first. Then upgrading to 2.13, and see if that goes smoothly as well.

Comment: That blog post is about 1.x to 2.x.

Comment: Oh correct, my mistake. It does cover the changes from DF to Beam, though I think if you're on DF 2.5 then you would have already covered such changes.